# Scale text by adjusting its immediately surrounding frame

Tags: graphics, function-construction, text

I want to ask if
it is possible to scale text in `Graphics`
by adjusting **its immediately surrounding frame**,
not the whole frame.

```
  Graphics[{Circle[],
  Inset[Style[x^2 + y^2 == 1, FontSize -> Scaled[0.1]], {0, 0}],
  Green, Rectangle[{0.5, 0.5}, {1, 1}]}, ImageSize -> 100]
```

[image]

In video, I do three jobs in order

1. move back and forth clicking the whole frame :
   size of circle, text, rectangle vary
2. move back and forth clicking the frame of green rectangle :
   size of rectangle varies
3. move back and forth clicking the frame of text :
   size of text does ***not*** vary

I want to make a graphic containing text, such that
moving back and forth while clicking the **immediately surrounding frame of text**
leads to change of the text size.

PS1) Using already rasterized image(of text) is not allowed.

PS2) This problem can also be understood in the following context :
Make texts to have the same property(a property of size change)
as other common graphics primitives like `Rectangle[]`, `Circle[]`.

Comment: If we can solve following problem, (single keyboard stroke shortcut in Graphics) 

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286678/custom-single-keystroke-shortcut-to-related-to-graphics 

I think we can solve this too

Comment: Found a practical smooth working solution! After some optimization, I'll post it.