# Custom Single keystroke shortcut related to `Graphics`

Tags: graphics, function-construction, keyboard

In the world of software, single keystroke shortcut exists but rare.

Because for single keystroke shortcut, there is a **prerequisite** :

*A single keystroke shortcut can be used in situations

where pressing a keystroke won't produce any input.*

In MMA, **I want to make a custom single keystroke shortcut** related with `Graphics` drawing tools, because I see it satisfies the above prerequisite.
Below is a screenshot of MMA tutorial. When a `Graphics` are selected, there are default single keystroke shortcut.

[image]

Above are drawing tools related shortcuts.
For example, `d` is for drawing `Disk`, `r` is for drawing `Rectangle`.
**In other words, except for the keys described above, they have completely no action now.**
For exmaple if you press `b` in your keyboard, it does nothing.

I think we can use this point to make a single stroke of `b` a new custom shortcut. (when the graphics are selected)

**Question :**
Can you make the single keystroke of `b`, to set a variable `varHope` to `1` ?

Just to make sure it is ever possible, I asked for very easy task.
If I find out it is actually possible, I want to apply it to fine-tune Graphics.

I want the shortcut to be temporary or cell-specific(cell chosen).

If this question has a solution, then it could also solve following problem :

[Scale text by adjusting its immediately surrounding frame](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286546/scale-text-by-adjusting-its-immediately-surrounding-frame)

It won't be as smooth as `Dynamic[]`, but adjusting the size of the frame to contain the text and pressing the shortcut `b` will make the text to be the maximum size that fit in the frame.